# how to remove html tags from a jenkins' RESTAPI expression?

Tags: jenkins

**What I have**

```
api/xml?depth=2&xpath=//lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/relativePath&wrapper=all
```

Which displays

```
<all>
  <relativePath>
    poky/files-in-image.txt
  </relativePath>
  <relativePath>
    poky/eglibc/core-image/image-info.txt
  </relativePath>
</all>
```

**To finish**

I just need to know if there is something I can add in the address to remove the html tags so only the paths are left?

Comment: The REST API returns structured data, so the client can parse it. If you want to remove the _XML_, it's best to do so in your client.

Comment: with my bash code for example? I know how to do it, but there is then nothing like and != in the url to remove words?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switch to using JSON instead of xpath.

If you need to parse the JSON, use JQ http://stedolan.github.io/jq/ in your bash script

Comment: thanks! I read about it seems good for parsing, but I cannot find if there would be a simple way to just parse every string between two HTML tags?

Comment: If you use the JSON API, you wont have any HTML tags to begin with.

Change your URL to something like this:
https://<jenkinsserver>/job/<your job>/lastSuccessfulBuild/api/json?depth=2&pretty=true

From here you can narrow down the result using more params, till you get a simplified JSON string. This final string you can parse with JQ.

If you want to use XML you cannot use JQ (since it is a json parser). You'll have to find some other XML parser